# How to change constants and useEffect in reactjs from a function to a render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have this code in a function

```
function Lobby () {
```

but I wanted to pass it on to `class Lobby extends Component {`
for a component with

```
render () {
    return (
```

but putting these const and useEffect ect .. gives me an error,
is there any way to "translate" this into a component?

I thank those who can help me

original code:

```
   function Lobby () {
    const [message, updateMessage] = useState('')
    const [messages, updateMessages] = useState([])

   

 useEffect(() => {
        const handleNewMessage = newMessage =>
            updateMessages([...messages, newMessage])
        socket.on('chat.message', handleNewMessage)
        return () => socket.off('chat.message', handleNewMessage)
    }, [messages])

   

 const handleFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (message.trim()) {
            socket.emit('chat.message', {
                userid: myId,
                lobby,
                username: username,
                message
            })
            updateMessage('') 
            
const recibesound = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0]
        recibesound.play()
        
   

 }

}

const handleInputChange = event =>
updateMessage(event.target.value)

////teste
const handleTesteChange = event =>
updateMessage(event.target.value)

const handleTesteSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (message.trim()) {
        socket.emit('chat.message', {
            userid: myId,
            message
            
   

 })
    updateMessage('') 
   
}

}
///teste



  

  return(  <div>
     //html
    </div>
)}
    
 

   export default Lobby;
```

goal:

```
class Lobby extends Component {

// same code


 render() {
   return(

<div>
 //html
</div>

 );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do does not make sense, What's your goal logically speaking? and why not simply render the Lobby in the <div> in class component?

Comment: that is, I have these constants within a function, and I want to pass them to a render component. if you place them inside a "class Lobby extends Component {" they give an error.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you are attempting to convert your hooks function component to a class component. You cannot use any of your hooks functions in a class component. You have to rewrite your class component using `this.setState()` instead of the useState hook (instead of updateMessage, and updateMessages) and `this.state.message` instead of 'message', and using the `componentDidUpdate` method instead of the useEffect hook. For your functions (handleInputChange), you can define them as method for your class. For your constant (recibesound), you can define it outside your class.

In short, you have to rewrite your component. I recommend viewing a React tutorial on class components.